# Как вставить формулы в Google Sheets именно методом batchUpdate

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Цель кода следующая:
Скопировать формулы из одного диапозона, потом вернуть их же обратно.
Я **НЕ** могу делать это стандартной `getRange().setFormulas()`
Потому что диапозон слишком большой и гугл выдает ошибку.
Я ее обошел, используя `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate`
Но я получаю следующую ошибку при выполнении кода:

> Exception: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed
> with error: Empty response

Я думаю это из-за того, что я пытаюсь передать в 'values' массив с полученный путем `getFormulas()`
Тк выше в программе точно такой же код, только с `getValues()` работает как надо.

Вот код:

```
  var formulsRange = v3_seet.getRange(yStart, xStart, yEnd, xEnd)
  var formuls = formulsRange.getFormulas()
  Logger.log("FORMULS COPIED")
  v3_seet.getRange(yStart, xStart, yEnd, xEnd).clear()
  Logger.log("range ARE CLEARED")


  var request = {
  'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
  'data': [
    {
        'range': shets[0]+'!' + formulsRange.getA1Notation(),
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': formuls
      }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, v3_sheetID);
  Logger.log("FORMULAS RESTORED")
```

Подскажите как вставить формулы в диапазон именно batchUpdate'ом.
Ну и не обязательный вопрос: как копировать формулы опять же при помощи batchUpdate'а.

Comment: Добавление в 'data' параметра `valueRenderOption': 'FORMATTED_VALUE',` не поменяли ситуацию. ошибка точно такая же. Массив с формулами точно заполнен. В чем проблема тогда вообще:/

Comment: `v3_seet`? Решили с квеста зайти? Пришлите проект.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, из-за пакетного изменения на стороне сервера очистка листа происходит после всех расчетов. Поэтому эту строку надо закомментировать.

Немного добавил методов и переопределил ваши переменные вне функции

```js
const v3_seet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const v3_sheetID = v3_seet.getParent().getId();
const shets = v3_seet.getParent().getSheets();
const [yStart, xStart, yEnd, xEnd] = [1, 1, 4, 4];

function userActionResetSheetToFormulas() {
  const formulsRange = v3_seet.getRange(yStart, xStart, yEnd, xEnd);
  const formuls = formulsRange.getFormulas();
  console.log("FORMULS COPIED")
  // v3_seet.getRange(yStart, xStart, yEnd, xEnd).clear();
  console.log("range ARE CLEARED")
  const request = {
    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
      {
        'range': shets[0].getName() + '!' + formulsRange.getA1Notation(),
        'values': formuls
      }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, v3_sheetID);
  console.log("FORMULAS RESTORED")
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]